# Select last timestamp from database with JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that selects groups and group postings. In the postings table there is a timestamp collumn, and a group_id. I need to select the greatest timestamp in the postings table, associated with the group id.

**Here's my query**

```
$query = "
    SELECT groups.group_name, groups.group_info, groups.group_tags, postings.timestamp 
    FROM groups 
    LEFT JOIN postings ON groups.group_id = postings.group_id 
    GROUP BY groups.group_id 
    ORDER BY `postings`.`timestamp` DESC
";
```

Comment: Answer your question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687827/mysql-group-by-with-order-by-desc][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687827/mysql-group-by-with-order-by-desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "
    SELECT groups.group_name, groups.group_info, groups.group_tags, max(postings.timestamp) 
    FROM groups 
    LEFT JOIN postings ON groups.group_id = postings.group_id 
    GROUP BY groups.group_id 
    ORDER BY `postings`.`timestamp` DESC
";
```

Comment: Nice work, I wasn't sure if max would do it, but next time I'll go with my instinct. Thanks!

Comment: Keep walking! Instinct is powerful!