# MySQL - GROUP BY with ORDER DESC not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi I am having a problem with following query.

```
SELECT id, user_id, cloth_id FROM `items` GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 3
```

I want the latest records with `group by` but somehow its showing old records.

I have also gone through [MySQL - Group by with Order by DESC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687827/mysql-group-by-with-order-by-desc) but not working as expected.

Comment: show table structure and data also

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: That's what's wrong with mysql. You *shouldn't be allowed* to select plain columns you're not grouping by! Add `id` to the group by and it will work. Also, _why_ are you using `Group by` if there's no aggregate functons in the select?

Comment: Try this : 
SELECT id, user_id, cloth_id FROM `items`  ORDER BY id desc GROUP BY user_id LIMIT 3

Comment: Yes it will work but I want a group by user_id

Comment: @RutushaJoshi - No its not working. Giving me an error

Comment: You mean you want distinct values?
So why not using 
`SELECT DISTNICT(user_id), id, cloth_id FROM items ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 3;` ?

Comment: @Liron - I have tried it but it is giving me same user_id

Comment: @VickyKuwar: Your query looks okay. Please check your DB data. Is it displayed wrong? Put the whole query in phpmyadmin's SQL section and check the result data.

Comment: @Liron Distinct is not a function, it works on all columns in the SELECT clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT i.id, i.user_id, i.cloth_id FROM
(
    SELECT max(id) as id, user_id FROM `items` GROUP BY user_id
) temp
LEFT JOIN `items` i on i.user_id = temp.user_id AND i.id = temp.id
```

in `temp` you get each user with the latest id.
in `i` you get the cloth_id for that combination